# How to set global variable in mysql stored procedure phpmyadmin?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

here is my procedure code for mysql phpmyadmin
** Procedure Code :**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `product_listing`(IN `pro_name` VARCHAR(265), IN `cat_id` VARCHAR(11), IN `status` VARCHAR(11))
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    DECLARE name VARCHAR(265);
    DECLARE main VARCHAR(265);      
    DECLARE pnmconcat VARCHAR(265);
    DECLARE pnmquery VARCHAR(265);    
    DECLARE respname VARCHAR(265);    
    set @pname := pro_name;
    set @cat_id := cat_id;
    set @status := status; 

    IF @pname IS NOT NULL THEN 

        SET pnmconcat = CONCAT("'%",@pname,"%'");
        SET pnmquery = ' and p_name like ';
        SET name = CONCAT(pnmquery, pnmconcat); 

    END IF;

    IF @cat_id IS NOT NULL THEN 

        SET name = CONCAT(' and cat_id=',@cat_id);  

    END IF;
    IF @status IS NOT NULL THEN 

        SET name = CONCAT(' and status=',@status);

    END IF;

    set @query := CONCAT("SELECT * from product WHERE p_id != ''", name, " ORDER BY p_id desc");

    PREPARE fquery FROM @query;

    EXECUTE fquery;

END
```

In above,

i want to set name variable as global varibal. but i could not able to set it. how i can store the name variable globally?

Comment: "@pname, @cat_id , @status" declare variable

Comment: There are no user defined global variables and they are no good idea either. Maybe you should describe, what you're actually trying to do. Or just store those values in a table.

Comment: i want to set name variable globally

Comment: actually i want to check this three variables pname, cat_id and status null or not if this is not null then one by one store concated value in name variable and at the end of all three condition i want to concat this name variable with query.

Comment: so i want to set this name variable globally. so i can use this name variable also after completion of if condition.